# How to Design and Architect a Hibernate Application

Tags: hibernate, architecture

I'm new to hibernate, I learned how to create the Entity and Mapping all the Entities using Hibernate annotations. I have used the below code configuration settings for creating the tables and saving the data into database, with JDBC methodology on Hibernate configuration settings.

```
  Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
  configuration.configure();

  ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
                                    applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

  SessionFactory sessionFactory = 
                            configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

  Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

  session.beginTransaction();

  /******************
         In between I have used the code
         for Loading and Saving the data
  *******************/ 

  session.getTransaction().commit();

  session.close();

  sessionFactory.close();
```

I have seen other examples using in which they have used Persistence Configuration.

Earlier when we use JDBC applications we will make a separate connection class and separate classes to handle prepareStatement or Statement class and will also try to manage the transaction.

Could somebody help me How we can make a best design for Hibernate kind of projects.

Comment: You can use spring framework.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question. I'll answer it anyway.

I use Spring for dependency injection and AOP transactional benefits.

A lot of people usually use SpringMVC and Hibernate as mentioned in the example link below. It is proven to be very good.

http://www.journaldev.com/3531/spring-mvc-hibernate-mysql-integration-crud-example-tutorial

Comment: Thanks Zeus for the good tutorial,if we are using spring this would be applicable. If we are using other than spring how do we work on this architecture.